# mysqlでのERROR 1045 (28000)を解決したい

Tags: mysql

dotinstallでmysqlを学んでいますが、以下のエラーで立ち止まっています。
以下のエラーを解消し、mydb01へ接続したいのですが、その方法がわかりません。
cduser01というユーザーへmydb01への権限を付与し、パスワード'6AVAkig2'で接続できるようにしていたのですが、1行目『dbuser01@~』としなければならないところ『dbuser』として先に進めた為、エラーになったのではないかと思われます。
削除して一からやり直しでも、その他の方法でもかまいません。
解決策をお聞かせいただけると幸いです。
宜しくお願いいたします。

```
mysql> create user dbuser@localhost identified by '6AVAkig2';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> grant all on mydb01.* to dbuser01@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> quit;
Bye
[vagrant@localhost mysql_lessons]$ mysql -u dbuser01 -p mydb01
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dbuser01'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: mysql -u dbuser01 -p で一度 Enter を押してからパスワード mydb01 を入力してみてください．

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/190582

Answer (score 1):

`dbuser` を削除して `dbuser01` を登録するところからやり直してください。

```
mysql> drop user dbuser@localhost;

mysql> create user dbuser01@localhost identified by '6AVAkig2';
```