# XAMPP付属のMySQL起動時の error:1045 を解決したい

Tags: mysql, xampp

現在「すらすらわかるPHP」という参考書を参考にしながらXAMPPをインストールし、MySQLを起動しようとしているのですが、

```
ERROR 1045(28000):Access denied for user '2170145''@''localhost ' (using password:No)
```

と表示されてMySQLが起動できません。対処法を教えてください

Comment: 重複候補: [mysqlでのERROR 1045 (28000)を解決したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/55144)

Comment: ユーザーを作成してログインしたら解決できました

Comment: このサイトでは「自己回答」も歓迎なので、解決に至った手順を投稿してもらうと他のユーザーの助けになると思います。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/211983

Comment: grant all privileges on *.* to 'ユーザ名'@'ホスト名' identified by 'パスワード名' with grant option で全権限を持つユーザを作成して、mysql -u ユーザ名 -pパスワードを入力したら接続できました。参考にしたサイトはあるのですが、履歴を削除してしまいまして分かりません。

Answer (score 1):

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'ユーザ名'@'ホスト名' identified by 'パスワード名' with grant option
```

で全権限を持つユーザを作成して、`mysql -u ユーザ名 -pパスワード` を入力したら接続できました。

参考にしたサイトはあるのですが、履歴を削除してしまいまして分かりません。

---

*この投稿は [@kbayashi さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59078/xampp%e4%bb%98%e5%b1%9e%e3%81%aemysql%e8%b5%b7%e5%8b%95%e6%99%82%e3%81%ae-error1045-%e3%82%92%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment63649_59078) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*